# how to port code perl switch-like statement for use with 5.8

Tags: perl, perl5.8

I have this particular code that is using perl 5.10 (for switch-like operation), but need to get it to work on 5.8.
What's another way to write this for 5.8? A preferred way/technique?

```
for my $detail ($Details1, $Details2) {
    for (keys %$detail) {
        when ('file') {
            print " File: $detail->{file}{path}\n";
            print "Bytes: $detail->{file}{size}\n";
        }

        when ('directory') {
            given (ref $result->{directory}) {
                when ('ARRAY') {
                    for my $entry (@{$detail->{directory}}) {
                        print "Directory: $entry->{path}\n";
                    }
                }
                when ('HASH') {
                    print "Directory: $detail->{directory}{path}\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replacing the `given`/`when`s with `if`/`elsif`s is simple enough.

```
for my $detail ( $Details1, $Details2 ) {

    for ( keys %$detail ) {

        if ( $_ eq 'file' ) {

            print " File: $detail->{file}{path}\n";
            print "Bytes: $detail->{file}{size}\n";
        }

        elsif ( $_ eq 'directory' ) {

            if ( ref $result->{directory} eq 'ARRAY' ) {

                for my $entry ( @{$detail->{directory}} ) {
                    print "Directory: $entry->{path}\n";
                }
            }

            if ( ref $result->{directory} eq 'HASH' ) {
                print "Directory: $detail->{directory}{path}\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm tempted to rewrite this as anonymous subs with a dispatch table.

Comment: thanks. if I have no data to return, can i also check `ref` for empty string?

Comment: `if ( ! $result->{directory} ) { ... }` or `if ( $result->{directory} ) eq '' ) { .. }` will match an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I think simple if-elsif would be sufficient to replace the switch-like code there.

The CPAN Switch is a source filter thus I guess it will generate similar code to if-elsif. And it has some limitation when you use it in eval:
"Due to the way source filters work in Perl, you can't use Switch inside an string eval."
http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Switch.html

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this with if-elsif and stuck with the nesting. Can you show me with if-elsif?

Comment: @cjd - please post your if elsif attempt so we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference is to use `for`, a regex, and a `do` block:

```
for my $detail ($Details1, $Details2) {
    for (keys %$detail) {

        /^file$/ && do {
            print " File: $detail->{file}{path}\n";
            print "Bytes: $detail->{file}{size}\n";
        };

        /^directory$/ && do {

            for (ref $result->{directory}) {

                /^ARRAY$/ && do {
                    for my $entry (@{$detail->{directory}}) {
                        print "Directory: $entry->{path}\n";
                    }
                };

                /^HASH$/ && do {
                    print "Directory: $detail->{directory}{path}\n";
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Don't forget the `;` after each `do` block.

EDIT: And don't forget to use `next` or `last` if you don't want to fall through to the next case.